# Android GridView in ScrollView will Flash

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

My entire application is built using ActivityGroup + Fragment, including home use nested ScrollView using GridView, when I switched to the home page from another page when sliding ScrollView will call the GridView's getView () method redrawn on the screen so flashes.

Bad user experience, how to solve?